# Add Rating Widget to a custom full content layout in drupal 7

Tags: nodes, rating

Can anyone know how to add a rate widget to a custom full content layout in drupal 7.

Let say I have a content type article.A have customized the layout with the help of Ds module for the full content.I have added my the field to my choose.Now I need a rating in the full content page with that the user can vote the article whether they like it or not.For that I added a module called Rate widget.With that I try to add a Thumb up/down to the full content page of the article but it is not showing me.Can any one know how to add rate widget to the custom full content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function to print rate field

```
rate_embed(&$node, $machine_name, $mode = RATE_FULL);
```

Like `print rate_embed($node, 'rate', $mode = RATE_FULL);`